# What would be the word used to name a person who is a professional video sharer?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have been wondering recently, mainly because of my recent site proposal on Area 51 named "YouTubers", what the word to name a professional video sharer is.

For YouTube it would be "YouTuber".

If I want to expand the term to apply to all video-sharing websites, what would the word be?

Comment: What do you mean by the term *professional* sharer?

Comment: Someone whose job is to share videos on websites such as YouTube to make money by ads and additional products

Comment: Traditionally, wouldn't they just be called *marketers* or *advertisers*?

Comment: No, what I mean by ads is just an ad before the video, not the video itself.

Comment: I was referring to those ads that show up alongside the videos, say on a side panel. The page owner is functioning as an advertiser (like a TV station, just with a much smaller reach) by displaying the ads and using items of interest to 'lure' people to view the ads (as a TV station does with TV shows).

Comment: Oh ok true. But I am more looking for just a word to better say video-sharer that relates to a profession, not 100% related to the ads they display. More for just the traction they cause and they views the videos receive

Comment: Which profession - videographer?

Comment: video blogger - vlogger?

Comment: IS there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Content creator](http://www.contentengine.tv/what-does-it-mean-to-be-a-content-creator/)

> Someone who is actively creating and publishing original content to an audience on one or more media platforms.

Wikipedia explains in detail about [Content creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_creation). Click to read more.

> Content creation is the contribution of information to any media and most especially to digital media for an end-user/audience in specific contexts. Content is "something that is to be expressed through some medium, as speech, writing or any of various arts" for self-expression, distribution, marketing and/or publication. Typical forms of content creation include maintaining and updating web sites, blogging, photography, videography, online commentary, the maintenance of social media accounts, and editing and distribution of digital media. A Pew survey described content creation as the creation of "the material people contribute to the online world."

For the special case of videos, you may use "Video Content Creator", although I've only seen "content creator" used, generally.

After googling, I've found [a lot of job profiles with the title "Video Content Creator"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22Video%20Content%20Creator%22), so there's that.

Comment: Great answer. Would "Video Content Creator" make sense in this context?

Comment: @sbswim It would make sense, but too big a name. I have only seen *content creator* used even in the case of videos. I guess if you go through the links I've shared, you'll get a better idea whether to include *video* along with *content creator*.

Comment: Awesome, works for me! I'll stick with just "Content Creator" it seems to fit what I am trying to accomplish.